# PostgreSQL in list, mixing string and int

Tags: postgresql

We are using PostgreSQL 11 and have a query from Redmine database. It is a query that works fine in MySQL 8 but on PostgreSQL we get an error.

```
SELECT fixed_version_id 
FROM issues WHERE 
((issues.fixed_version_id IN ('current_version','2')));
```

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "current_version"
LINE 1: ...d FROM issues WHERE ((issues.fixed_version_id IN ('current_v...

I understand that fixed_version_id is an int and that I quering strings. However, is other SQL like MySQL 8 you can do this and it actually returns values. But in PostgreSQL we get an error. Not sure if we have it setup wrong or if this is just the way PostgreSQL works?

Any help would be most appreciated thank you.

We ran this query

```
SELECT fixed_version_id 
FROM issues 
WHERE ((issues.fixed_version_id IN ('current_version','2')));
```

We were expecting Not to get an error.

Comment: How can you have `fixed_version_id` as an integer equal to `'current_version'` which is a string ? As you can understand postgres do not allow you to mix various types together, you need to convert the data so that they have the same type before comparing them together, maybe `WHERE CAST(issues.fixed_version_id AS text) IN (...)`

Comment: Just remove the string `'current_version'` from your IN list. An integer column can never be equal to that string, so removing it won't change the outcome of the query. This is not how "PostgreSQL works" - this is how SQL works. If MySQL really accepts that and returns something that is not equal to `2`  then this sounds like a serious bug in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is a tightly typed language (seems MySql does not adhere to the standard). The only correction is using the correct type - in this case integer. But you can `CAST' an integer to text and compare.

SQL Standard:

```
WHERE ((cast (issues.fixed_version_id as text) IN ('current_version','2')));
```

Postgresql extension:

```
WHERE ((issues.fixed_version_id::text IN ('current_version','2')));
```

Comment: You can also simply remove the `'current_version'` string from the IN list. An integer column will never be equal to a string `'current_version'` even if that integer is converted to a text value.

Comment: The question is not how to fix it but more why. And I think I have received the answer that PostgreSQL just doesn't handle as the developer expected. It seems to me it was poorly written code. We have no control over that unfortunately but I think I have the answer I need to take back to management.

Comment: @RickV: what kind of developer would expect that the string `'current_version'` would ever match a value in an integer column? That's like trying to write `if ("current_version" == 42) ...` in Java